# How to implement function from MainActivity to Fragment with searchview.setOnQueryTextListener

Tags: java, android, mysql

I want to call function loadRestaurantlist() in my MainActivity and I call it on my fragment using ((MainActivity)getActivity()).loadRestaurantlist(); but my application stops when i start the fragment. Does anyone know why it's not working? I have no problem when just displaying data into the recyclerview without searchview. But when I use a searchview with setOnQueryTextListener my app stopped working.

//MainActivity.java

public void loadRestaurantlist() {

```
    svrestaurant = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.sv);
    rvrestaurant = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);


    svrestaurant.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            new Downloader(MainActivity.this, urlAddress, query, rvrestaurant).execute();
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
            new Downloader(MainActivity.this, urlAddress, query, rvrestaurant).execute();
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

//RestaurantFragment.java

public class RestaurantFragment extends Fragment {

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2preference, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();

   ((MainActivity)getActivity()).loadRestaurantlist();

}
```

}

Comment: Can you post the exception that you see in your logcat

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I found out the i was missing this       rvrestaurant.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
rvrestaurant.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

Comment: Great to know :) glad that it's working for you now